# Meta-analysis and meta-regression results don't agree

Tags: r, regression, interaction, meta-analysis, meta-regression

In the context of a (multilevel) meta-analysis, I want to caluclate grand effect size estimates for subsets of data corresponding to the levels of a categorical variable.
Using the example below, I'd like to calculate the grand effect size for Gifted students and NotGifted students. I thought of approaching this two ways: run two meta-analyses (one with Gifted students, the other with NotGifted students), or include Gifted status as a moderator in an analysis inclusive of all students (i.e. a meta-regression (though I knwo this term is frowned upon)).
To my confusion, the two approaches produce different values for effect sizes for Gifted and NotGifted students. I have two questions.

Why are the results of the two methods different? Which approach is better, i.e. which is a better estimator of the true effect size for Gifted or NotGifted students?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
library(metafor)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
School = rep(1:5, each = 4),
Class = rep(1:2, times = 10),
Pupil = rep(letters[1:4], times = 5),
Gifted = sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size = 20, replace = TRUE),
yi = rnorm(20, 70, 15),
V = rnorm(20, mean = 5, 2))

Gifted <- rma.mv(yi, V, random = list(~ 1 | Class, ~ 1 | School), 
             method = 'REML', data = subset(df, Gifted == 'Yes'))
NotGifted <- rma.mv(yi, V, random = list(~ 1 | Class, ~ 1 | School), 
                method = 'REML', data = subset(df, Gifted == 'No'))
Regression <- rma.mv(yi ~ Gifted, V, random = list(~ 1 | Class, ~ 1 | School), 
                 method = 'REML', data = df)

matrix(round(c(NotGifted$b, Gifted$b, Regression$b[1], Regression$b[1] + Regression$b[2]), 3), 
   2, 2, TRUE, list(' ' = c('Subset', 'Regression'), ' ' = c('NotGifted', 'Gifted')))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, why are they different? This is to be expected when you do random effects meta-analysis. In a fixed effects analysis, the weight depends only on the variance for that study. With random effects, the weight depends on the variance (as with fixed effects) but also with the tau-squared estimate, which takes into account variation between studies - studies further from the grand mean are weighted less. If tau-squared is zero the two sets of values will agree.

Second: Which one to use? I would use the meta-regression model, but interpretation of meta-regression is a bit tricky. See, for example: http://www.nicedsu.org.uk/TSD3%20Heterogeneity.final%20report.08.05.12.pdf

Comment: Spot on. A while ago, I wrote this up on the metafor package website. See: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates